# Pandas faster DataFrame lookups by value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working on a project where I'm dealing with somewhat large data sets. I have a dataframe `transactions` and another `users`.

Iterating through the transactions dataframe is no problem. I used `timeit` and it takes just under a minute to do so. My second dataframe `users` has 1,000 rows. Both of these dataframes have a column `email`. Essentially what i'm trying to do is get the `userId` in the row in `users` that matches the `email` in each `transactions` row. My current approach looks like this:

```
for row in transactions.itertuples():
    userId = users[users['email'] == getattr(row, 'email')]['userId'].values[0]
```

This simple lookup works, however it's too slow for my use case. I kept it running for over an hour and it still wasn't finished running. I'm wondering if there's potentially a faster way to do this lookup (maybe get the runtime down to minutes instead of hours)?

Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Have you checked out the Pandas merge function?  You could use an inner join on email.  Merge information at [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Comment: @DarrylG This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Just tested it and it creates a new dataframe with the transactions including the matching userIds. So all I have to do is drop the columns that I don't want and i'm set. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Harrison--glad I could help.  Yep, I've used it several times in the way you mentioned.  It's very fast.